# use Youtube-dl in a php script

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-dl

Is there a way to use the youtube-dl in a php script or there's a php library that does the same thing? I need to obtain the direct link of a youtube video so the user can download it

Comment: Just run the according shell command, `youtube-dl -g %s`.

Answer (score 1):

Yea, there is a library for Youtube-DL:
<del>http://chellem.github.io/Youtube-dl-php/</del>

**Update 23.08.2016**: http://labzone.github.io/Youtube-dl-php/

Comment: The Link broken :(